# Inno Setup Reading a Registry Gives Empty String

Tags: inno-setup

I am a bit new to Inno Setup so spare me if this question sounds childish. Let me show you the code first:

```
RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,'SOFTWARE\Altera Corporation\Quartus','Quartus Version',QR_ver);
Result := True;
```

QR_ver should contain the value that is inside the 'Quartus Version' but instead it returns an empty string. And yes I checked 'Quartus Version' is not empty itself. It contains a value '14.0'

Please Help

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you are on a 64-bit system and thus you have verified that value in 64-bit regedit. If that is so, use `HKLM64` root key instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Default regedit on 64-bit system is 64-bit and shows 64-bit view on registry (32-bit view shows under the `Wow6432Node` node). Inno Setup maps (by default) to 32-bit view and thus you couldn't read it.

Comment: Are you using 64-bit system ? Were you checking that value in 64-bit regedit ? Is that key really under the 32-bit registry view ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah what you mentioned was totally right and once I used HKLM64 my problem was solved. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball tells me that you are on a 64-bit system and thus you have verified that value in 64-bit regedit. If that is so, use HKLM64 root key instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Default regedit on 64-bit system is 64-bit and shows 64-bit view on registry (32-bit view shows under the Wow6432Node node). Inno Setup maps (by default) to 32-bit view and thus you couldn't read it. –  (Credits: TLama)